# what does it mean that the coefficient of variation equals 100%

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I am taking a Probability and Statistics course. We know that:

> coefficient of variation  = (standard deviation / mean) * 100%

Geometrically, what does it mean that the coefficient of variation = 100%. I know that in that case, the standard deviation must be equal to the mean, but I can't imagine the case in which that equality occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient of variation simply expresses the standard deviation as a fraction of the mean value, and is best applied to ratio-scale data that has a meaningful zero value. A low CV indicates that the distribution is narrow about the mean, while a high CV indicates that the distribution has more variability about the mean. A CV at or above 1 is usually considered high variability, as the standard deviation is equal to or higher than the mean.

An exponential distribution is an example of a distribution that has a coefficient of variation equal to 1, as it has mean equal to its standard deviation. CVs above 1 may be seen in ratio-scale data with heavy tails, as in a hyperexponential distribution. In ratio-scale data, a value cannot be further from the mean than zero on the low end, but can be arbitrarily high on the upper end - these upper tail values can contribute greatly to the standard deviation.

Comment: Abstractly, whether one cares about what one can do with ratio scale data is synonymous with whether one with cares about preserving the action of the similarity group in Stevens' typology.

Comment: Is the exponential distribution the only one that is positive and has CV=1? Are there discrete distributions with the same property?

Comment: @xyz It's certainly not the only distribution with that property. You can increase the CV of any starting distribution just by re-weighting it away from the mean value, since changing a value changes the SD more than the mean. Keep moving away from the mean enough, and you'll find CV>1. Discrete distributions can also have this property, for example, consider the distribution of outcomes for a 6-sided die with a face reading 100 instead of 6.